# Python: why robinhood API doesn't response to request to push ticker into watchlist?

Tags: python, json, algorithm, api, python-requests

Hey guys I have a problem wiht the robin-stocks library. The authentication is working fine so I didn't post the first lines of authentication. What I'm trying to do is push a list of stocks into a watchlist in my RH account. The library has a function called "robin_stocks.account.post_symbols_to_watchlist(inputSymbols, name='Default')" found here: https://robin-stocks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#robin_stocks.account.unlink_bank_account

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
inputSymbolslist=['NKLA']

def post_symbols_to_watchlist(inputSymbols, name='Andre3'):
    """Posts multiple stock tickers to a watchlist.

    :param inputSymbols: May be a single stock ticker or a list of stock tickers.
    :type inputSymbols: str or list
    :param name: The name of the watchlist to post data to.
    :type name: Optional[str]
    :returns: Returns result of the post request.

    """
    symbols = helper.inputs_to_set(inputSymbols)
    payload = {
       'symbols': ','.join(symbols)
    }

    print(payload)
    
    url = urls.watchlists(name, True)
    print(url)
    data = helper.request_post(url, payload)
    print(data)

    return(data)

post_symbols_to_watchlist(inputSymbolslist,name='Andre3')
```

OUTPUT from command prompt line:

{'symbols': 'NKLA'}

https://api.robinhood.com/watchlists/Andre3/bulk_add/

{'detail': 'Not found.'}

Can you guys take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong. It's possible the API may have gone changes recently and the library wasn't updated accordingly. Appreciate your help!

Andre

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you refer to and quoted in your code clearly states:

> Parameters:
> inputSymbols (str or list) – May be a single stock ticker or a list of stock tickers.

not JSON.

Try  to call Robinhood's function with string or list of strings as first parameter.

```
post_symbols_to_watchlist(['NKLA'], name=Andre3)
```

Comment: I tried the changes mentioned but still got the same error: {'symbols': 'NKLA'}
https://api.robinhood.com/watchlists/Andre3/bulk_add/
{'detail': 'Not found.'}

Comment: Could it be a problem with the helper.request_post function? Thanks so much!

Comment: It will be nice if you provide _your code_, excluding sensitive infor of course. Do you have Robinhood API installed with PIP?

Comment: I installed the robin-stocks library that interacts with the unofficial robinhood api using pip install. I don't believe I can install a robinhood API, can i? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Adding more information on my question.

From the code I posted, the helper and url py files are called on.

HELPER CODE found here: https://robin-stocks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/

URLS CODE found here:

"""Contains all the url endpoints for interacting with Robinhood API."""
from robin_stocks.helper import id_for_chain, id_for_stock

## Login

def login_url():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/oauth2/token/')

def challenge_url(challenge_id):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/challenge/{0}/respond/'.format(challenge_id))

## Profiles

def account_profile():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/accounts/')

def basic_profile():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/user/basic_info/')

def investment_profile():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/user/investment_profile/')

def portfolio_profile():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/portfolios/')

def security_profile():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/user/additional_info/')

def user_profile():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/user/')

def portfolis_historicals(account_number):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/portfolios/historicals/{0}/'.format(account_number))

## Stocks

def earnings():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/marketdata/earnings/')

def events():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/options/events/')

def fundamentals():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/fundamentals/')

def historicals():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/quotes/historicals/')

def instruments():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/instruments/')

def news(symbol):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/midlands/news/{0}/?'.format(symbol))

def popularity(symbol):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/instruments/{0}/popularity/'.format(id_for_stock(symbol)))

def quotes():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/quotes/')

def ratings(symbol):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/midlands/ratings/{0}/'.format(id_for_stock(symbol)))

def splits(symbol):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/instruments/{0}/splits/'.format(id_for_stock(symbol)))

## account

def phoenix():
return('https://phoenix.robinhood.com/accounts/unified')

def positions():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/positions/')

def banktransfers():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/ach/transfers/')

def cardtransactions():
return('https://minerva.robinhood.com/history/transactions/')

def daytrades(account):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/accounts/{0}/recent_day_trades/'.format(account))

def dividends():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/dividends/')

def documents():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/documents/')

def linked(id=None, unlink=False):
if unlink:
return('https://api.robinhood.com/ach/relationships/{0}/unlink/'.format(id))
if id:
return('https://api.robinhood.com/ach/relationships/{0}/'.format(id))
else:
return('https://api.robinhood.com/ach/relationships/')

def margin():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/margin/calls/')

def margininterest():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/cash_journal/margin_interest_charges/')

def notifications(tracker=False):
if tracker:
return('https://api.robinhood.com/midlands/notifications/notification_tracker/')
else:
return('https://api.robinhood.com/notifications/devices/')

def referral():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/midlands/referral/')

def stockloan():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/stock_loan/payments/')

def subscription():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/subscription/subscription_fees/')

def wiretransfers():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/wire/transfers')

def watchlists(name=None, add=False):
if add:
return('https://api.robinhood.com/watchlists/{0}/bulk_add/'.format(name))

```
if name:
    return('https://api.robinhood.com/midlands/lists/items/')
else:
    return('https://api.robinhood.com/midlands/lists/default/')
```

def watchlist_delete(name, instrument):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/watchlists/{}/{}/instruments'.format(name,instrument))
#return('https://api.robinhood.com/watchlists/{}/{}/'.format(name,instrument))

## markets

def currency():
return('https://nummus.robinhood.com/currency_pairs/')

def markets():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/markets/')

def market_hours(market, date):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/markets/{}/hours/{}/'.format(market, date))

def movers_sp500():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/midlands/movers/sp500/')

def get_100_most_popular():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/midlands/tags/tag/100-most-popular/')

def movers_top():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/midlands/tags/tag/top-movers/')

def market_category(category):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/midlands/tags/tag/{}/'.format(category))

## options

def aggregate():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/options/aggregate_positions/')

def chains(symbol):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/options/chains/{0}/'.format(id_for_chain(symbol)))

def option_historicals(id):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/marketdata/options/historicals/{0}/'.format(id))

def option_instruments(id=None):
if id:
return('https://api.robinhood.com/options/instruments/{0}/'.format(id))
else:
return('https://api.robinhood.com/options/instruments/')

def option_orders(orderID=None):
if orderID:
return('https://api.robinhood.com/options/orders/{0}/'.format(orderID))
else:
return('https://api.robinhood.com/options/orders/')

def option_positions():
return('https://api.robinhood.com/options/positions/')

def marketdata_options(id):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/marketdata/options/{0}/'.format(id))

## pricebook

def marketdata_quotes(id):
return ('https://api.robinhood.com/marketdata/quotes/{0}/'.format(id))

def marketdata_pricebook(id):
return ('https://api.robinhood.com/marketdata/pricebook/snapshots/{0}/'.format(id))

## crypto

def order_crypto():
return('https://nummus.robinhood.com/orders/')

def crypto_account():
return('https://nummus.robinhood.com/accounts/')

def crypto_currency_pairs():
return('https://nummus.robinhood.com/currency_pairs/')

def crypto_quote(id):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/marketdata/forex/quotes/{0}/'.format(id))

def crypto_holdings():
return('https://nummus.robinhood.com/holdings/')

def crypto_historical(id):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/marketdata/forex/historicals/{0}/'.format(id))

def crypto_orders(orderID=None):
if orderID:
return('https://nummus.robinhood.com/orders/{0}/'.format(orderID))
else:
return('https://nummus.robinhood.com/orders/')

def crypto_cancel(id):
return('https://nummus.robinhood.com/orders/{0}/cancel/'.format(id))

## orders

def cancel(url):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/orders/{0}/cancel/'.format(url))

def option_cancel(id):
return('https://api.robinhood.com/options/orders/{0}/cancel/'.format(id))

def orders(orderID=None):
if orderID:
return('https://api.robinhood.com/orders/{0}/'.format(orderID))
else:
return('https://api.robinhood.com/orders/')

Comment: def watchlists(name=None, add=False):
    if add:
        return('https://api.robinhood.com/watchlists/{0}/bulk_add/'.format(name))

    if name:
        return('https://api.robinhood.com/midlands/lists/items/')
    else:
        return('https://api.robinhood.com/midlands/lists/default/')

def watchlist_delete(name, instrument):
    return('https://api.robinhood.com/watchlists/{}/{}/instruments'.format(name,instrument))
    #return('https://api.robinhood.com/watchlists/{}/{}/'.format(name,instrument))
# markets

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a comma-delimited string of ticker symbols as the parameter instead of just one ticker symbol. When I played around with this functionality I could only get it to work if I had more than one ticker in the string. Try "NKLA,AAPL" instead of "NKLA" and see if that works. If it does then maybe you can send a parameter string like "NKLA,NKLA" to get it to register the ticker in the watchlist.